# External image editor not found?

Tags: external-applications, path

When I try to quick edit in texture paint I get an error saying that it couldn't find an image editor even though there is one (see photo)

[image: path to external image editor in blender]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You entered a link on your desktop.

Change the image editor to the executable `C:\Program Files\Krita (x64)\bin\krita.exe` (or where you have installed Krita)

Comment: this file is a link (.lnk) not the real program executable (.exe). You can get the real path in the link properties (right click you link, not in blender, select properties)

Answer (score 0):

What you linked to is to a desktop shortcut (.ink), not the actual executable (.exe) which it needs to be.

I had a different issue when I got that error. For me, it had an issue with the parenthesis, so I simply renamed the `...\Krita (x64)\...` to `...\Kritax64\...`