# Image path '.' not found, image may be packed or unsaved

Tags: uv-image-editor, external-applications

I'm trying to use the `Image` -> `Edit Externally` menu option, but I get the error message: `Image path '.' not found, image may be packed or unsaved`.

My Image Editor preference is set to: `/usr/bin/inkscape` which does exist and is a regular executable file:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/inkscape 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12406776 Jan 22  2014 /usr/bin/inkscape

$ file /usr/bin/inkscape 
/usr/bin/inkscape: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=44e349b8449f6a5de13f0224193b6157bdda0ae6, stripped
```

I have seen another post that asks a similar question, [External image editor not found?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24739/external-image-editor-not-found).  However, it that question a file system link was used for the editor whereas I am using an executable.

My blender version:

```
$ blender --version
Blender 2.77 (sub 0)
    build date: 2016-04-08
    build time: 19:05:34
    build commit date: 2016-04-05
    build commit time: 18:12
    build hash: abf6f08
    build platform: Linux
    build type: RelWithDebInfo
    build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wnonnull -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=gnu99  -msse2  -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing
    build c++ flags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations  -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp  -msse2  -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing
    build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/build/blender-mzA9Fo/blender-2.77-a-1459879952/source/creator/blender.map'
    build system: CMake
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The sequence of steps I follow leading up to the error:

- When using the video sequence editor, press F12 to open the current frame
- In the image editor:

  - Click the `Image` menu
  - Click `Save All Images`
  - Click the `Edit Externally` sub menu
  - Error message `Image path '.' not found, image may be packed or unsaved.` is displayed by Blender

Note that the `Save Image` menu option is greyed out.

[image]

When I click on the image list, I only see the `Render Result`.

[image]

Comment: I think your problem is not so much the executable or the path to the application, but more the path to the image, see the message `Image path '.' not found`. Are you using a packed image inside the .blend file? Can inkscape reach the image you are trying to use?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've updated the question with the steps I followed.

Comment: Is it a render or the current frame you are trying to edit? Did you explicitly save the render to a file? External editors can only work on files saved to disk, no external application can directly read temporary or unsaved images that only exist in memory inside blender without a file

Comment: I believe it is just the current frame that is shown in the image editor.  I have updated my question to reflect that fact that clicking `Save All Images` does not help.

Comment: Go through all the images in your image editor's list and check if one has the name "unnamed" or shows an asterisk in the image editor's menu.
It's almost always an unsaved image. This won't be saved by clicking "Save all Images".

Comment: As for the update (we have a screenshot! YAY!)... what happens if you choose "Save as Image"?

Comment: I'm presented with the file dialog asking where I want to save the image.  Apologies for the rookie question - how do I see the list of all images in the editor?

Comment: Click on the image icon with the up+down arrows on the right side of the "Image" menu in your screenshot. Also, Blender is not very good in keeping track of images you might have deleted outside of Blender.

Comment: I've updated the question - all I see is `Render Result`.

Comment: when the 'save image' button is greyed out, this can mean that you haven't given the file a filename yet. You need to run 'save as' before, point to a location on your hard drive, and save. after that, the save image button will become available. It would be logic that images which have no filename (and thus no harddrive location) yet would be skipped by a save all images operator imho.

Comment: What's with "Save as Image"? Is there a file with the same name in Blender's file selector, if you try "Save as image"? If not, save "Render Result" as image and try again.

Comment: Oh, and btw... inkscape is an vector graphics editor. Blender produces with some exceptions raster graphics. You might want to try gimp.